# rake aborted! ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'challenges' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I run this rake:

```
task monthly_report: :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    if user.challenges.present? && user.challenges.any?
      UserMailer.monthly_report(user).deliver_now  
    end
  end
end
```

Now maybe in the `each` method itself is there a way to not send to user's who don't have any challenges?

I keep getting this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'challenges' for nil:NilClass`after I run in production`heroku run rake monthly_report

A user `has_many` challenges and challenges `belongs_to` user.

**user_mailer.rb**

```
  def monthly_report(user)
    @user = user if user.email.present?
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Sorry! Please Ignore | Testing Email - Monthly Challenges Report"
  end
```

**monthly_report.html.erb**

```
Accomplished: <%= @user.challenges.accomplished.count %> Ongoing: <%= @user.challenges.unaccomplished.count %>

    <% if @user.challenges.accomplished.present? %>
        <% @user.challenges.accomplished.order("deadline ASC").each do |challenge| %>
            <% if challenge.date_started != nil %>
                <%= link_to challenge_url(challenge) do %>
                    <%= challenge.name %> <%= challenge.committed_description %> for <%= challenge.days_challenged %> Days
        <% end %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <% if challenge.deadline.present? %>
            <span style="display: inline; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-size: 75%; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; color: #fff; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: .25em; background-color: #446CB3; text-decoration: none;"><%= challenge.deadline.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></span>
        <% end %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to challenge_url(challenge) do %>
                    <%= challenge.name %>
                <% end %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <% if challenge.deadline.present? %>
                    <span style="display: inline; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-size: 75%; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; color: #fff; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: .25em; background-color: #446CB3; text-decoration: none;"><%= challenge.deadline.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></span>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        None.       
    <% end %>
```

Comment: the error says that you dont have any `users`, `undefined method 'challenges' for nil:NilClass`, means the user is nill. make sure your database contains users.

Comment: so, you can try,   `if user && user.challenges.present? && user.challenges.any?`

Comment: please put your view and mail also so able to check this problem is raised

Comment: That could be part of it @Sravan, but with your adjustment I still get the error. I have users, but some have been deleted so that maybe part of the cause. Just still don't know how to solve it

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com can you post the full stack trace of error ? & are you 100% sure `@user = user if user.email.present?` works i.e all users have an email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your rake task

```
task monthly_report: :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    if user.email.present? && user.challenges.present? && user.challenges.any?
      UserMailer.monthly_report(user).deliver_now  
    end
  end
end
```

I think error raising if your user dose not have any email in th record try this

Comment: Let's use User.find_each instead! User.all is risky if you have so many users. Btw, monthly report just will be sent with some conditions, a better approach would be User.where(something), the performance would be improved a lot!